# Problem in dismissing fullscreen mode of MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my application i am using MPMoviePlayerViewController to play online video. The video should play in fullscreen mode when in landscape and the fullscreen mode should be dismissed when it rotates to portrait mode.
I am able to play the video in fullscreen mode. But not able to dismiss it when the device orientation changes to portrait mode.

I am using [mpController.moviePlayer setFullscreen:FALSE animated:YES];

Someone please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're trying to detect the orientation change in the view controller that present `MPMoviePlayerViewController`? This code won't be fired after the movie player view controller is presented because it—not its parent—will receive the rotation events.

You can, however, subscribe to the device rotation notifications and dismiss the movie player view controller whenever you detect a rotation to portrait:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[defaultCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(deviceOrientationDidChange:) name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

// Present MPMoviePlayerViewController here
```

Elsewhere in the same view controller:

```
- (void)deviceOrientationDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIDevice *currentDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    [currentDevice endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

    if (...)        // Check currentDevice.orientation to see if it's what you want
    {
        // Do whatever you want now that you have the orientation you want
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}
```

Comment: I am not presenting the MPMoviePlayerViewController. I am using addSubView.

Comment: Okay, well, that shouldn't really change anything. You still need to hook into the logic when the device rotates to determine what to do with your movie player view.

Answer (score 0):

Set observer for `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` or `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification`, check new required orientation and set new mode for MPMoviePlayerViewController.